# detect long touch (WPF and Microsoft Surface)

Tags: wpf, touch, pixelsense

Is there any way I can detect a long touch over a TextBlock (or a Label)?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do that in an awaitable fashion. Create a timer with specific interval. Start it when user tapped and return the method when timer elapsed. If user release the hand, return the method with false flag.

```
public static Task<bool> TouchHold(this FrameworkElement element, TimeSpan duration)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> task = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    timer.Interval = duration;

    MouseButtonEventHandler touchUpHandler = delegate
    {
        timer.Stop();
        if (task.Task.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
        {
            task.SetResult(false);
        }
    };

    element.PreviewMouseUp += touchUpHandler;

    timer.Tick += delegate
    {
        element.PreviewMouseUp -= touchUpHandler;
        timer.Stop();
        task.SetResult(true);
    };

    timer.Start();
    return task.Task;
}
```

For more information, read this [post](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/08/07/touch-and-hold-gesture-awaitable/).

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will co-exist with the surface long touch = right click event.

Comment: But this doesn't work as expected! The Task of a TaskCompletionSource is in the WaitingForActivation State. The SetResult(false) is never fired. It's better to check for task.Task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion. And better use TrySetResult than SetResult.

Comment: GreenEyedAndy is right! Made his corrections and it is working great in both ways now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no built in way so you would have to do something like this

•   Capture the start time on the TouchDown event of the control

•   Compare this to the release time in the TouchUup event

•   If the two are different by X then run your long touch code

There might be a few things you have to code around but that is the basic idea

Comment: you'll also want to ensure that the touch hasn't moved more than ~1/2 inch over the course of this time and have an animation that shows the user that you are watching their finger so they realize that they are supposed to hold still

Answer (score 2):

There is an event called `TouchAndHoldGesture` and `PreviewTouchHoldGesture`

Answer (score 0):

Long touch, or press and hold as I think it's formally named, can be detected through the right click event.
It may be that, if you are using a Surface Window, that the right click event is disabled.

Comment: We used Surface SDK components to enable touch in a project, and right click events (as well as click events) were indeed triggered. It was Surface SDK 2.0 beta, if that matters, and we used a regular WPF window.

Comment: were you using Surface hardware?  a standard windows pc will give you mouse events but real Surface input will not

Comment: How? I found no property on the right click MouseButtonEventArgs that tell me anything like the duration...

Answer (score 0):

There is a ContactHoldGesture event on all Surface controls that you can use.  But, and I say this as the guy responsible for creating this feature during my time at Microsoft, this event is very poorly designed and should not be used.  It doesn't tell you when the system has decided that a finger has moved too much to count as a "hold" and it doesn't give you information needed to draw an animation telling the user that a "hold" is underway.  Your much better off doing what @Kevin suggested and building your own implementation.

Comment: Seriously?
For the moment, in a quick-and-dirty prototype, I still resorted to the ContactHoldGesture. I will however keep in mind what you suggested. One more question, @Robert: where can I find reference of all the events that Surface controls have in the 2.0 SDK? I was not able to find anything satisfying yet, as most documentation I can find concerns version 1.0.

Comment: @Tilvia - Surface 2 mostly leverages the events that WPF 4 has built in for touch.  go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx and search for the word "touch" within that page.  extra things (like this crappy 'hold' gesture i apologize for) are exposed by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.input.touchextensions_members.aspx