# Selection with touch Long press button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my xaml

```
    <usercontrol xxxxxx

                 xxxxxxx

    <grid >

    <Grid.rowdefinition>

          <rowdefinition></rowdefinition>

          <rowdefinition></rowdefinition>

   </Grid.rowdefinition>

 <grid Grid.row=2>

 <canvas x:name="canvas" Button.click = "Somefunction">

 </canvas>

</grid>
</usercontrol>
```

So I have a User control with 2 rows in a grid, I have a canvas in 2nd row. Well, I am dynamically creating buttons and adding them as a children to the canvas. Now, at present, when any button present in canvas is clicked,  this somefunction which i have defined in code behind will be invoked.  In somefunction, i have some code which acts according to the button clicked inside the canvas.

Now, What I want is, I want to select 2 buttons, but, selection should happen on long press of the one button followed by long press of the second button. Once, both are selected, I want to execute my own code.

How to code long press button selection on the dynamically created,attached buttons in the canvas explained as above. I found some links in the stackoverflow and codeproject. But, That really didnt gave me proper idea on how to go about with the present xaml and programmed logic. Hence, Please suggest on this, with basis to the above xaml structure and explained logic of program.

Thank you,

Rakesh.N

Comment: I don't know much about gestures, but *long* key press sounds fairly simple to organize: start timer on button down, stop on button up, if timer is expired - you had your *long* press.

Comment: @user3483952 Did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113604/detect-long-touch-wpf-and-microsoft-surface

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1396&lang=en) might help you out...